# What is this tall, vigorous weed?

Tags: identification, weeds

I've got thousands of these coming up in my yard. In shady spots, this weed is not as big. In areas with full sun, it's huge.

<sub>*Click on photo for full size*</sub>

[image: unknown weed]

They have short roots and pull out of the ground cleanly and usually in one piece.

I'd like to know what it's called.

Comment: Hi! Did you have those last year? Did they ever flower? If so, can you describe the flower? Thanks!

Comment: They flowered last year, since posting this I found a document from my city's website that lists common weeds and it looks like this might be Nipplewort. The flowers it had last year were small, yellow, similar to daisy or dandelion. It looked like the pictures for Nipplewort.

Comment: Did it develop fruit?

Comment: No fruit of any kind as far as I know. just seeds (it's *everywhere*)

Comment: How does it smell if you crush some?

Comment: I will let you know when I get home. I'm still 80% sure it's Nipplewort, I am in Portland, Oregon and the city website lists it as a common noxious weed. What is confusing me, is that most photos I can find of Nipplewort show rather skimpy foliage with few leaves that are widely spaced. The specimens growing in my yard are much denser, with leaves coming off the main stalk every 1.5-2". Could this just be due to the soil quality being better in my yard than for example the area on the side of a road?

Comment: It looks kind of like a Physalis of some sort. What do the flowers look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it looks remarkably like Nipplewort (Lapsana) to me too - it can grow very bushily, specially if its cropped, and it does love a nice rich, cultivated soil, though it will grow anywhere, just not so strongly in less favourable conditions. Usual height is 1-1.2 metres, so if yours aren't bigger than that, I'd say not only does it look like nipplewort, it is nipplewort.

Comment: There are a few that look like they've bolted so I'm going to let them bloom just to make sure. In the mean time, the rest of these are making great compost.

Answer (score 2):

Both the growth pattern and timing/mass growth sound like, and it looks like, "Garlic Mustard", [Alliaria petiolata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliaria_petiolata) a highly invasive (but easy to pull, I have to say, having been "blessed" with creeping buttercup which is not) weed (or herb.)

[image: Garlic mustard wikipedia picture]

Comment: I agree based on the limited information provided, but the example in Cathode's post seems a bit oddly shaped or proportioned. I can't really explain.

Comment: It did not have white flowers last year, they were yellow. and resembled small dandelion flowers.

Comment: No, sorry, that's not a corect identification. The leaves in OPs post are too pointy, Alaria is more heart-shaped, always with a deep indentation at the stem side. Only the top leaves near the flowers are really pointy. Besides, there would be almost round leaves at the base before the flower stem emerges. If any doubt remains, crushing a leaf will set free the characteristic garlicky smell, which I'm quite sure OP's specimen don't have. I'm linking to the [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knoblauchsrauke), which has better pictures than the English version.